# I'm trying to change the text of my div dynamically but it is not working

Tags: innerhtml

I'm trying to do something as simple as changing the text in my `<p>` tag from "hello" to "goodbye: but I can't get it to work.

Here is my html

```
<body>
    <div id="passwordBox">
        <!-- <div id="title">
            <span>PASSWORD GENERATOR</span>
        </div> -->
        <p id="password">Hello</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

here is my js

```
document.getElementById('password').innerHTML = "goodbye";
```

My js is linked correctly in my head. Other functions that I had in there were working correctly. So I'm wondering what the issue is. I'm sure it's something simple that I am just not seeing but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

HTML execution happens top-down. HTML calls each script it finds while parsing the HTML document. Since you placed your script in "head" the script gets called immediately. When the script is called, your DOM is not yet ready and your script accesses your DOM element returning a null. So load the script after your DOM is loaded completely ie., after body or just before ""

So the ideal code should look like:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p id="password">Hello</p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    document.getElementByID("password").innerHTML="goodbye";
  </script>
</html>
```

Or you can still load your script from the head, but just add a button along with event listener (`onClick`) which calls the JavaScript function when the button is clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function changeContent() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="goodbye";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="password">Hello</p>
    <button onclick="changeContent()">Try it</button>
  </body>
</html>
```